# Convert library to autoconfiguration/starter while in use

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter, spring-autoconfiguration

Our project has a library that defines several beans.
Historically, it's a simple artifact, no autoconfig enabled and all other applications are using this artifact together with `@ComponentScan`.

Now, I realize, that it should rather be an autoconfiguration dependency, with `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` etc., to provide more flexibility for the application.

According to the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration.locating-auto-configuration-candidates), autoconfigurations should not be a candidate for component scanning. As far as I understand, it is only critical for situations when your configuration is `@ConditionalOn` something, so it does not get scanned twice.

What would be the correct way to perform the transition from library + `@ComponentScan` to autoconfiguration, assuming all the consumers of the same library cannot be updated instanly?

Will it cause any major issues if the autoconfig get scanned? Or can it be limited to cases with the usage of `@ConditionalOn` etc?

I know it should be possible to create another maven artifact, make it dependant on the first one and define autoconfiguration, but I would like to avoid creating another now.

Thanks, Pavlo

Comment: What is the problem? Release the new library as starter on nexus with a new version of course and then start removing `@ComponentScan` from the consumers and update the version.

Comment: There are several libs like that and they share the common package root, so most of the consumers use the common part on the component scan. So if new version is released - every consumer will have to be updated. I know the setup sounds horrible, but it’s a big project and not everything in my hands.

Comment: Do you have N libraries with the same package defining beans in them? So you can use one package in the `@ComponentScan`? This is a hell. You should refactor all the package of the libriaries if I’ve not misunderstood

Comment: Libs and packages go like ‘com.acme.lib1’, ‘com.acme.lib2’ and applications use ‘@ComponentScan(“com.acme”) to avoid listing all. 
Totally agree on refactoring, hence the question.

Comment: This is not so bad as I was thinking. Every library as it’s own package. To go faster just use in each library a `@Configuration` (that you must use because it my must be linked in spring.factories) with `@ComponentScan(basePackages=com.acme.libn)`. It’s a different story  if you want to start to use `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` or something like that. In this case you have to start defining and constructing the beans in the configuration class. But no need to refactor the pakages in the consumers. I think those are the roads

Comment: Of course you have to finish the refactor on each library before starting refactoring the consumers for the problem of @ComponentScan with the parent package. Once you have finished with the libraries you can start to deploy one consumer at time. The other option e will be to change the com.acme package in the libriaries to avoid the component scan

Answer (score 1):

So I have this solution in my mind:

1. Start simple in each starter library start defining one `@Configuration` class with a `@ComponentScan(basePackages=“com.acme.libn)` when done release all the libriaries on the nexus (Note that this is a bad practice the starters should define the beans in the `@Configuration` classes but for this step will be used as a workaround).
2. Go on the consumers and remove `@ComponentScan`, update library and deploy. This will be the fastest way to remove the scanning of the beans on the main `com.acme` package.
3. Now you are free to work on each library as you prefer. Example: refactor the packages, declaring beans in the `@Configuration`, use `@ConditionalOn…`, remove `@ComponentScan`, use more `@Configuration` classes (you have to link them in the spring.factories file), start using prefix for using propeties defined in the consumers …, you can work in parallel on this task with your team. And release one library when it’s ready if you don’t want to release all of them together.
4. Re go in the consumers and refactor if needed, update the library that are ready and deploy. Go to step 3 till the libriaries are finished.

Otherwise you have to refactor `com.acme` package in each library and in each consumers, keeping the `@ComponentScan` in the consumers. When done with all the libriaries you can then remove it. You don’t have to do it all together, you can do it one library at time and one consumer at time.

PS: if you have entities and you are using spring-data in your libraries let me know I will update the answer because there is extra work to do.

I’ve read the documentation you have linked and I don’t know if it’s outdated or not. I’m using spring.factories file as for example stated [here](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-custom-starter).I’m using spring boot 2.7.0. So check the correct configuration for the version of spring boot you are using

**EDIT**
I've read better the documentation and digged into the spring boot code `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.import` can be used to tell spring where the `@Configuration\@AutoCOnfiguration` classes are. You can also use `META-INF\spring.factories` to declare the `@Configuration\@AutoConfiguration` classes. In the source code they are using the first option. Honestly I've not undersood the difference.

I think I've also discovered how to expose `@RestController` or any other component in a starter without using `@ComponentScan` as they say in the doc you must use `@Import` example:

```
@Configuration
@Import({RestController.class, SomeService.class})
class ConfigurationClass {
}
@RestController
class RestController {
}
@Service
class SomeService {
}
```

This will make the `SomeService` avaiable for injection, and I think this will expose automatically the endpoint defined in `RestController`, like spring-boot-starter-actuator.

For the repositories of spring-data-jpa you have to use this in the `ConfigurationClass` example:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureAfter(JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example")
@Import({Entity1.class, Entity2.class})
class ConfigurationClass {
}
@Entity
public class Entity1 {
}
@Entity
public class Entity2 {
}
```

In this way the repositories interfaces present in `com.example` will be ready for injection in the configuration class or outside the jar. In my project I was able to load entities only using `@EntityScan` in the consumer of the starter I have to make a try with @Import.

All the things that I've writed in the **EDIT** section must be tested, the only exception is the configuration for jpa repositories with `@EntityScan` on the consumer. I've had no time for test right now.

So in the end you can remove then `@ComponentScan` in the first step I've writed and use `@Import`, but you have to list all the classes that are annotated like `@Component\@Service...`. In this way you don't have to declare and construct all the beans of the step 3 in the configuration classes.

**EDIT 2** I've made some test you will find the code [here](https://github.com/paolopiccinini/spring-boot-starter-example)
what i discovered:

1. Adding the configuration classes in `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.import` doesn't work, you have to use `META-INF\spring.factories` if you check the code I've commented the configuration class in the file
2. `@Import` with entities doesn't work, unlikly you have to put `@EntityScan` in the cosnumer declaring all packages where the entities are.

For the rest everithing is fine. You can play with it:

```
POST localhost:8080/someEntities
request body
{
    "name" : "entity1"        
}
response
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "entity1"
}
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "entity1"
}
GET localhost:8080/someEntities/1
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "entity1"
}
```

**EDIT 3** from spring boot v2.7 the classes annotated with `@AutoConfiguration` are migrated to a new file `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` (nothe the final s so imports) see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73484864/spring-boot-custom-starter-org-springframework-boot-autoconfigure-autoconfigurat) for more info. The configuration classes declared in `spring.factories` will still be honored

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Although it does not completely solve the problem (the set up is a bit more complicated), but it gives a good starting point. Thanks!

Comment: Keep in mind that you can always depend on older version of the libraries. I wrote the various steps in order to not refactor the pakages of the libraries, so less work