# Spring boot custom starter org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.import not detecting configuration classes version 2.7.2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-boot-starter

I've read that I should not open an issue on github so I ask here. I've digged into the code and for example `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure` doesn't define the `@Configuration\@AutoConfiguration` classes inside `META-INF/spring.factories` follow the content of the file:

```
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=\
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.metrics.ValidationFailureAnalyzer
```

I've checked and `ValidationFailureAnalyzer` is not even annotated with `@Configuration\@AutoConfiguration`. Then I see the file `META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` declaring all the classes `@AutoConfiguration` follow a little extraction of the file:

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitHealthContributorAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.audit.AuditEventsEndpointAutoConfiguration
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.availability.AvailabilityHealthContributorAutoConfiguration
...
```

all these classes are annotated with `@AutoConfiguration`. So far so good If we read the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration.locating-auto-configuration-candidates) they say that:

> Spring Boot checks for the presence of a META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports file within your published jar.

Indeed if we import:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
</dependency>
```

everything works just fine. I'm not skilled with gradle but I don't see any special dependecy in `spring-boot-actuator-starter` or `spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure`.
Searching on google I've found a discussion [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-289633) where they say:

> In Spring Boot v. 2.7 auto-configuration registration is moved from spring.factories to a new file named META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports.
> Each line contains the fully qualified name of the auto-configuration.
> For backwards compatibility, entries in spring.factories will still be honored.

But honestly I've tryed to move the configuration classes in the new file but the configuration class is not loaded. I've writed an example [here](https://github.com/paolopiccinini/spring-boot-starter-example).
My `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` file:

```
com.example.springbootstarterexample.configuration.Config
```

If I move to the old configuration `spring.factries` everything works fine.

My `@AutoConfiguration` class:

```
@AutoConfiguration(after = JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
//@AutoConfigureAfter(JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.example.springbootstarterexample.repository")
@Import({SomeServiceImpl.class, SomeEntityController.class})
public class ExampleAutoConfiguration {

}
```

am I doing something wrong? why the `spring-boot-starter-actuator` works and my `spring-boot-starter-example` dosn't?

Comment: I'm also searching for info on it to start some tests. Assure you didn't forget to put the `@AutoConfiguration` annotation on the top-level of your auto-configuration classes as mentioned [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7.0-M2-Release-Notes). I think that this is mandatory for the new imports file to work.

Comment: I’ve tryed everything.  `@Configuration\@AutoConfoguration` , copiy the dependency in the pom of `spring-boot-starter-actuator/auto configure`, refactor the package of the configuration class with autoconfiguration in it. Nothing worked

Comment: Tryed also to remove all annotation from `ExampleAutoConfiguration` leaving only `@AutoCOnfiguration` and declaring a single bean, still the configuration is not loaded

Comment: I have made some tests yesterday and I was able to make it work. I will provide a sample in a github public repository but I am using kotlin with gradle and not java with maven.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your file is called `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.import`,

and must be `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` (notice the extra `s`) at the end.

Comment: I’ve not access to my laptop right  now. After I test I will accept don’t worry. I’m not that kind of users…

Comment: Anyway was you able to setup a starter with entities in it? I’ve tryed to load entities in the starter with `@Import` But it doesn’t work. The only way is to use `@EntityScan` in the consumer because if also in the consumer we have entities we declare all the packages of the entities. But this breaks the autoconfiguration meaning. If it’s off tipici I will ask another question. I wonder how `spring-boot-batch-starter` Works, because it uses some tables in order to make the batch work

Comment: @Pp88 I did not start that project, no, just skimmed over it... you can ask a separate question and I'l take a look

Comment: the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73538904/spring-boot-custom-starter-define-entities-in-it-without-using-entityscan-is) is here if interested @Eugene

Comment: that's important to mention that format is different now, here is an example https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports

Answer (score 1):

Put the file `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfiguration.imports` under `resource/META-INF/spring package-> ~ProjectName/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/`

This file then can contain your custom configuration file fully qualified name
like example below
`com.test.autoconfigure.MongoApplicationDBConfig`